# for case let using enumerated() method

Tags: swift

I'm confused.

I can loop over an array with type casting using this:

```
for case let provider as ProviderModel in providers {
    provider.activated = true
}
```

But how can I implement here index Swift-style?
Something like this:

```
for (index, provider <<type cast>>) in providers.enumerated() {
    provider.activated = true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a tuple pattern:

```
for case (let offset, let provider as ProviderModel) in providers.enumerated() {
    // ...
}
```

or equivalently:

```
for case let (offset, provider as ProviderModel) in providers.enumerated() {
    // ...
}
```

A self-contained example:

```
let numbersAndStrings: [Any] = [1, "2", 3, "4", 5]

for case let (offset, number as Int) in numbersAndStrings.enumerated() {
    print(number, "at offset", offset)
}
```

Output:

```
1 at offset 0
3 at offset 2
5 at offset 4
```